# How to create a TCP Server in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I started learning networking with python can somebody help me out with this code as I am unable to connect more than 5 clients at a time. Can someone please suggest me a solution for this?

```
def main():
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind(('', listening_port))
        s.listen(5)
        print "[*] Initializing Sockets ... Done"
        print "[*] Sockets Binded Successfully ..."
        print("[*] Server Started Successfully [%d]\n" % (listening_port))
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        sys.exit(2)
    while 1:
        try:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            data = conn.recv(buffer_size)
            start_new_thread(conn_string, (conn, data, addr))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            s.close()
            print "\n[*] Proxy Server Shutting Down ..."
            sys.exit(1)
    s.close()

def conn_string(conn, data, addr):
    print conn
    print addr
    print data
```

Comment: start_new_thread is an inbuilt function of thread library. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the python socket API:

> socket.listen(backlog)
>
> Listen for connections made to the socket. The
> backlog argument specifies the maximum number of queued connections
> and should be at least 0; the maximum value is system-dependent
> (usually 5), the minimum value is forced to 0.

Increase the number from 5 to the number of simultaneous connections you wish to have to the server.

Comment: This is incorrect. The listen backlog is how many connections can be queued up. The server thread just accepts the TCP session and moves the work to another thread, so it can go back to listening mode.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is **incorrect.** I'll try to explain you why.

`listen` takes an argument of *queued connections*. That means, how many new connections can be put into the queue. That's why even in the documentation it's specified 5, while obviously servers serves more than 5 concurrent clients usually.

Once a socket is created (accepted) it is being forwarded to another thread, which performs the actual work. This allows to the `listening` thread moves back to listening mode and wait for more clients.

The problem with your code is, your *main thread* which is the listening thread **actually reads data from buffer**, where it shouldn't. The `recv()` function blocks (read more about I/O stream blocking)

You need to move the reading process from the listening thread to the worker; and make sure to `close()` the socket when it's done. The code would look something like this:

```
def main():
    try:
        ...
        s.listen(5)
    except Exception, e:
        ...
    while 1:
        try:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            start_new_thread(conn_string, (conn, addr))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            s.close()
            print "\n[*] Proxy Server Shutting Down ..."
            sys.exit(1)
    s.close()

def conn_string(conn, addr):
    data = conn.recv(buffer_size)
    print conn
    print addr
    print data
    conn.close()
```